# Search boxes for individuals content types

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

I'm trying to have a search facility for different content types on their term pages.

So I have a view that lists all the terms that link through to a page that lists all the nodes that has that term. On this page I want to have a search box which can be used to search any node within it's content type. Now this is fine if I only needed to search one content type, using the [Custom Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search) module I can tell Drupal to only search one content type.

However I need to do exactly the same as above but for a different content type. What would be the best way of implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer in the end if anyone else comes here searching for a solution. Turns out you could do what I wanted with the custom searech module I mentioned in my question. If you go into modules in the admin area there's also a custom search block module that comes with custom search that can be enabled. This gives you the ability to add as many blocks with different confiurations as you please. You then just go into blocks in structure and configure to your hearts content for each block then use those blocks where you want, job done! Just need to work out how to change the template now!